# Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 - Updating C#.NET (Xamarin v4.1.0)

Tags: xamarin

Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 - Updating C#.NET (Xamarin v4.1.0) leads to an error. Please suggest alternate method for updating/using Xamarin in VS2015 community edition.
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please find here quick way Xamarin installation http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/quick-start-tutorial-manual-or-quick-way-of-xamarin-and-simulator-installation/